Symmetry and angular momentum in the Jahn-Teller paper
In the original paper of Jahn et Teller (https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1937.0142, section I-Two Examples) are described two examples: a linear molecule and one with square planar configuration of nuclei.
The part I'll refer to is:

There is a similarity between the two examples in that, in the first example once the wavefunction on any half-plane through the axis is given, then it is determined by symmetry for all other such half-planes: a rotation through the angle $\theta$ multiply the wave function by $e^{i\lambda\theta}$, where $\lambda$ is the axial component of the orbital angular momentum. In the second example, on the other hand, the symmetry about the axis through the centre of the square, although considerably reduced, still determine the wavefunction completely on any four half-planes at right angles to each other, once the wave function has been given on any one of them. The function is again multiplied by $e^{i\lambda\theta}$, where here $\theta$ is restricted to the values $\pi/2, -\pi/2, \pi$ and $\lambda$ can have the values 0, 1, -1. The state with $|\lambda|=1$ is again two-fold degenerate.

In particular I'm searching for an explanation (intuitive or rigorous) on the role of $\lambda$ in the case of the second example.
How starting from the character table, in general, you can deduce the z-component of angular momentum?
The part on angle is more clear to me from symmetry arguments.

In the second example lambda does not have the significance of an angular momentum; angular momentum about the axis does not commute with the Hamiltonian, (though C4 rotations do).

@dharr thanks for your comment. Is there a way to deduce the possible values of $\lambda$ from irreducibile representations?

We first consider a linear molecule with $C_{\infty \mathrm{v}}$ or $
D_{\infty \mathrm{h}}$ symmetry, but we will work with only the $C_{\infty }$
subgroup, representing rotations around the internuclear ($z$) axis. The
one-electron wavefunction takes the form $g(\eta ,\xi )\exp (\operatorname{i}
m\varphi ).$ We are are working in a coordinate system where $\varphi $ is
the azimuthal angle (angle about the $z$ axis) and $\eta $ and $\xi $ are
the other two coordinates. The wavefunction is an eigenfunction of the
operator for the angular momentum around the $z$ axis:
$$
\widehat{l}_{z}=-\operatorname{i}\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }
$$
which has eigenvalues $m\hbar $, $m=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots $ and commutes with the
Hamiltonian, i.e., $m$ is a good quantum number. So if we know the
wavefunction $\psi _{0}$ at one angle, say $\varphi =0$, then as we rotate
by an angle $\theta $ around the same axis, the wavefunction at the new
angle (half plane in 3d) is $\psi _{0}\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta ),$ i.e., is multiplied
by $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$. This value $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$ is what Jahn and Teller
call $\exp (\operatorname{i}\lambda \theta )$.  The quantum number $m$
corresponds to angular momentum value $m\hbar $. However in "units of $\hbar 
$" (atomic units) the angular momentum has the value $m$, which probably
explains the loose but strictly incorrect reference to $\lambda $ as "the
axial component of the orbital angular momentum".
Now for the link to symmetry. Let $\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$ be the
operator for rotation by an arbitrary angle $\theta $ around this axis, i.e,
$$
\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }(f(\varphi ))=f(\varphi +\theta )
$$
A symmetry operator such as $\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$ has
eigenvalues with magnitude 1 and commutes with all observables. $\widehat{C}
_{\infty }^{\theta }$ and $\widehat{l}_{z}$ commute, and each commutes with
the Hamiltonian. So the wavefunction is a eigenfunction of $\widehat{C}
_{\infty }^{\theta }$ and $\widehat{l}_{z}$. The link between these is
that because the system has rotational symmetry through an arbitrary angle,
angular momentum around the axis is conserved, and the corresponding quantum
number $m$ is a good quantum number. (This is a form of Noether's
theorem.) If we apply $\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$ to the
wavefunction, we can find its eigenvalue to be $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$:
$$
\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }g(\eta ,\xi )\exp (\operatorname{i}m\varphi
)=g(\eta ,\xi )\exp (\operatorname{i}m(\varphi +\theta ))=\exp (\operatorname{i}%
m\theta )g(\eta ,\xi )\exp (\operatorname{i}m\varphi )
$$
In other words multiplying the wavefunction by $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\varphi )$
corresponds to rotation by $\theta $, as we already saw. If we apply $
\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$ twice, we see that  $\widehat{C}_{\infty
}^{2\theta }=$ $\left( \widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }\right) ^{2}$ has
eigenvalue $\exp (\operatorname{i}m2\theta )$. Multiplication by $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$ can
represent $\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$. In terms of the $C_{\infty 
\mathrm{v}}$ character table, this means that the values $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$
become characters of the operator $\widehat{C}_{\infty }^{\theta }$.  The
wavefunctions with $+m$ and $-m$ are degenerate, and the "two dimensional" $E
$ representations collect the $\pm m$ one-dimensional representations
together; we may add $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\theta )$ and $\exp (-\operatorname{i}m\theta )$ to get $
2\cos (m\theta )$. It is usual in spectroscopy to refer to a quantum number $
\lambda =|m|$ and designate the corresponding orbitals for $\lambda
=0,1,2,\ldots $ as $\sigma ,\pi ,\delta ,\ldots $. (though this usage for $
\lambda $ is different from Jahn and Teller's). So the value of the quantum number $\lambda $
labels the irreducible representations.
For the square planar complex, the symmetry operators for rotation by
multiples of $90^\circ $ are $C_{4}^{0}=E$, $C_{4}$, $C_{4}^{2}=C_{2}$, $C_{4}^{3}$.
Because we do not have a continuous symmetry any more (not all $\theta $ are
possible), angular momentum about the axis is not conserved (doesn't commute
with the Hamiltonian), $m$ is no longer a good quantum number, and the
wavefunction no longer has a factor $\exp (\operatorname{i}m\varphi )$. But the $
C_{4}^{i}$ symmetry operators commute with the Hamiltonian, and determine
the possible symmetries of the wavefunction, which we can find from the
character table of the $C_4$ point group in the usual way.
In the context of LCAO MO theory, for an MO made from $\mathrm{s}$ orbitals
at the corners of the square we can find the coefficients by reading off the
characters in one of the four one-dimensional irreducible representations
of the $C_{4}$ point group. The characters in this point group are $\exp (
\operatorname{i}n\theta )$ with $\theta = 0, \pi /2, \pi, 3 \pi /2$,  and with $n$ labelling the
irreducible representations with $n=0$ ($\mathrm{A}$), $n=2$ ($\mathrm{B}$), and $n=\pm 1$ the two components of $E$ (see the Wikipedia
page for these components separately; often they are added to give real
characters.)  So in these MOs, if we start from a value of the wavefunction $
\psi _{0}$ at some angle $\varphi$, then at rotations $\theta =0,\pi
/2,\pi ,3\pi /2=-\pi /2$ we have multiplied the wavefunction by $\exp (
\operatorname{i}n\theta )$. The analogy with the linear molecules is clear; in
this case Jahn and Teller's $\lambda $ is what I have called $n$.
